# Does wicket lose hold of the HTML components after a rearrangement through JavaScript?

Tags: wicket

I have a repeating component in wicked which needs to be added and deleted as per the user requirement. The maximum number of component is predefined. So I am adding the components at start up and hiding and showing based on need. I am required to change the arrangement of the components in the HTML markup when there is any deletion of the component. I use JavaScript for this. I want to know if wicket would lose hold of the components if I do this.

```
<div wicket:id="borrowerTabs" id="borrowerTabs">
    <span wicket:id="borrowerTab1" id="borrowerTab1" ></span>
    <span wicket:id="borrowerTab2" id="borrowerTab2" ></span>
    <span wicket:id="borrowerTab3" id="borrowerTab3" ></span>
    <span wicket:id="borrowerTab4" id="borrowerTab4" ></span>
    <button wicket:id="addBorrower" id="addBorrower" type="button"></button>
    <button wicket:id="deleteBorrower" id="deleteBorrower" onclick="updateUIForDeleteBorrower()" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

If delete the borrowerTab3, contents inside borrowerTab4 will be replacing the contents inside borrowerTab3 and the model objects too will be swapped though I do not do a target.add(borrowerTab3). Now while form submission, I am not getting the values of the fields inside borrowerTab3.

Comment: This does not really answer your question, so I am adding it as a comment. I think a list editor wicket component will be better for your needs than the JavaScript fiddling you are trying to do. Refer to this turorial about how to build one: http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/building-a-listeditor-form-component/ Note: I had to change the code a bit when I last used it, but in general this approach works fine for dynamic list editors.

Comment: if you delete the node from the DOM, when you call target.add(component) wicket will fail because the AJAX  cannot find the element you specify in the markup, however if you delete the child nodes of borrowerTab3 (for example JQuery.empty()) it will work, hope helps

Comment: @osdamv : I am replacing the child nodes and in wicket side. For example, say, I am deleting borrowerTab3, I replace the child node of borrowerTab3 with Child node of borrowerTab4. And in wicket side, I get the model object of borrowerTab4 and assign it to the model of borrowerTab3. **I am not doing a target.add(component)** in whole process.

Comment: Have tired adding an AjaxBehavior to borrowerTabs and then calling it from your Javascript? You could pass the markupid of the tab your deleting from js to wicket and update the borrowerTabs' component model appropriately.

Comment: @drobson: Yes I know which tab I am currently in and hence I know which tab I am deleting. The models are replaced correctly as I see while debugging. But when I submit the form, the inputs in the fields are not reflected in the model object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps but try component.setVisible(false) in your java code to hide it.